# Problems with THREE,js canvasTexture

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, textures, drawimage

Here is my problem.

I've made a Terraingeometry from a DEM. Now I download some OSM-Tiles to use them as texture for my geometry.

Each time a new Tile arrives, my callback processMapImage is called:

```
function processMapImage( img, y, x)
{
myImages[y][x] = img;
myTilesToLoad--;
    
if( myTilesToLoad == 0)
    {
    var tilesy = myImages.length;
    var tilesx = myImages[0].length;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width  = 256*tilesx;
    canvas.height = 256*tilesy;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for( y = 0; y < tilesy; y++)
        {
        for( x = 0; x < tilesx; x++)
            ctx.drawImage( myImages[y][x], 256*x, 256*y, 256, 256);
        }
    tex = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas);
    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: tex});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( myTerrainGeometry, mat);
    mesh.rotateX( -Math.PI/2);
    scene.add( mesh);
    }
}
```

As long as not all Tiles are loaded, I store them in myImages. When all tiles are loaded, I create a canvas and draw all tiles to that canvas. Then I create texture, material and together with my terraingeometry finally the mesh and add it to the scene.

But the model shows only a black surface of my terrain.

I have tested so far:

When I use a simple colored phong-texture everthing is ok, So lightning, geometry, camera are fine.
When I display my canvas in a browser all tiles are there and correct ordered. So the canvas is ok.
When I draw something else (lines, rectangles) on my canvas, it will be correct shown as texture on my geometry. So the texturing is ok. Only my Images don't work.

Any Idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: If you’ve added lights, and they illuminate the terrain as expected, then it might be your loop. Does `myTilesToLoad` ever reach 0? Also, do your nested loops iterate as many times as you expect? It’s hard to tell where the issue is without seeing the code execute. Could be that your images are black, or not loading?

Comment: The loop is ok, because I can display the generated canvas, which is complete and contains all requested tiles at their correct position.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.

I had to add

```
            img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

to my Images on creation in order to enable CORS.